# Notification Listener does not read all notifications posted

Tags: java, android, notifications

Following is the simple code to read notifications

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = (String)extras.getCharSequence("android.title");
    String text="";
    if (extras.getCharSequence("android.text") != null) {
        text =(String) extras.getCharSequence("android.text");
        Log.d("service1",text);
    }
    if(text.trim().equals("")) {
        if (extras.getCharSequenceArray("android.textLines") != null) {
            Log.d("service", "in 1st if");
            CharSequence[] charText = extras.getCharSequenceArray("android.textLines");
            if (charText.length > 0) {
                text = (String) charText[charText.length - 1];
                Log.d("service2", text);
            }
        }
    }
    if(text.trim().equals("")) {
        if (extras.getCharSequence("android.infoText") != null) {
            Log.d("service", "in 2nd if");
            text = (String) extras.getCharSequence("android.infoText");
            Log.d("service2", text);
        }
    }
```

The code works perfectly fine for white background notifications. However, I receive `text =null` for notifications with black background.

I have tried using remote views. But, it does not even read white background notifications

Can Somebody help ?

**EDIT**:
[This is the screenshot from my mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eX4r.png)
I have checked this code on API 21 version mobile. I totally agree battery doctor, weather notifications which appear in grayish background, use remote views and this method won't read these notifications.

I receive `BBC news`, `Screenshot captured` and `4 applications updated` notification.

However, for notification with `Computer program that can read your mind` and `Exercise helps live through your first heart..`, I only receive package name and both title and text is null.

Comment: How does the text correlate at all with the background? Im not sure that is a valid conclusion. Please specify your error clearer. And if they are custom remote views, you won't be able to find it that way.

Comment: @JoxTraex, Please check edit section.